# How to send an embedded code into server side -PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, post

One of my HTML form accept embedded code as input and saves in MySQL database using PHP. I have used

```
jQuery('#userFrm').serialize();
```

to send data to the back end and accepted in the server side as

`$_POST['video_url']`

but it showing error as follows

```
The requested URL /'//www.hudl.com/embed/video/3/4897424/5721e0c70428ae20e4de8b97/' was not found on this server.
```

when input

`<iframe src='//www.hudl.com/embed/video/3/4897424/5721e0c70428ae20e4de8b97' width='640' height='360' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>`

in the textarea.

Whether there we need to include an extra parameter in the form to send as embedded code to backend?

Answer (score 0):

Hi when you inserting the data into database use mysql_escape_string . and when you print or getting the result use `stripslashes($row['video']);`